# how to decompile this anti luajit decompiler?

Tags: lua, luajit

here is lua - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H9aDCEFgyMVoL7vikmcvbmMnTimAW2xm/view?usp=share_link
what method is this? how to decompile it?

I'm new in this area, I don't understand how to decompile this, I hope someone can help

Comment: How is this file supposed to be used? It does not run for me on any Lua version.

Comment: its lua script for neverlose csgo cheat, grenade helper (auto throwing grenades)

Comment: Do you know by any chance what Lua version they use, and whether it's custom? Mimak found out it's LuaJIT 2 tho my 2.1 installation can't run it.

Comment: I'm very sorry, this is for gamesense cheat, here is its documentation - https://gamesensical.gitbook.io/docs/developers/development/compiling

Answer (score 2):

The file is a [LuaJIT 2](https://luajit.org/) binary - file signature:

```
1B 4C 4A 02 02 CF 03 02 01 10 01 0F 04 5C 0B 00        .LJ..Ď.......\..
```

The binary format is explained [here](https://gist.github.com/GitSparTV/a0e36f2bc52badbce7723cb2e552285a). I tried using [luajit-decompiler](https://github.com/Dr-MTN/luajit-decompiler) though the decompilation fails.

One interesting thing is this string present in the binary, perhaps you can contact the author on Discord:

```
---------------------------  anti luajit decompiler :)   by sapphyrus -- Phil#9999  ---------------------------
```

Comment: He does not give me the source code, that's why I ask.

Comment: [LjTools](https://github.com/rochus-keller/LjTools) looks promising, I haven't tried it out due to Linux-only support

Comment: also i can share documentation of this lua - gamesensical.gitbook.io/docs/developers/development/compiling

Comment: @frenzied the docs tell you how to compile the source code, your file is luajit bytecode (the extension should be `.ljbc` to avoid confusion)

Comment: maybe i need attach it too... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k5ZlY77S4UO4JsjJOtYwahi2hE1r_oW2/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

My decompiler works with your files, though be aware that they are heavily obfuscated so you will need to de-obfuscate them yourself.

The bytecode is also missing debug info, which means that the decompiled lua code will have lots of auto generated variables since the original variable names are lost.

https://github.com/marsinator358/luajit-decompiler-v2